# Try to parse phone number from html, but get a lot of empty rows

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I can't understand how to get phone number from html by regex. I check my regex [here](https://regex101.com), it works and must get the number from this [link](https://a101.ru)

I try to parse like that:

```
import requests
import re

url = 'https://a101.ru'
r = requests.get(url)
html = r.text
result = re.findall('((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}', html)
print(result)

And get this: 
[(u'', u'', u''), (u'', u'', u'').....(u'+7 ', u'+7', u'(495) ')....(u'', u'', u'')]
```

Comment: Required reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/10553976

Comment: Even if you could parse XML, would the element ` <a href="tel:+7(495)221-40-21">+7 (495) 221-40-21</a>` provide one or two results?

Comment: @wallyk two results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the regex to spot the `tel:` part of the href

```
import re
import requests

r = requests.get('https://a101.ru', verify=False)
print re.findall(r'tel:(.*?)">', r.text)
```

For that page it would spot 4 matches:

```
['+7(495)221-40-21', '+7(495)221-40-21', '+7(495)221-40-21', '+7(495)221-40-21']
```

Normally I would use BeautifulSoup to parse the file correctly and extract the information, but for very specific minor uses, regex could be used with care.

---

You can obtain the same results with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('https://a101.ru', verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
print([tel['href'][4:] for tel in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'tel:'))])
```

Comment: Can i use this regex ('tel:(.*?)">') to all html's to take phone numbers?

Comment: The `tel:` prefix is used by phones to actually dial the number, not all websites add it. If it is used, you can be fairly certain that it is a valid number.